# What kind of a sata cord do I need to power my from Gigabyte mini pc?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, power-supply, sata

I've got a mini computer that doesn't have a plug from its motherboard (model number is a gigabyte MZBAYAG to its sata drive.  I have one sata port on the motherboard and another small white rectangular 10 pin (2x5) port labeled "satapw"  my guess is this is the cable I need to plug in.

I've got a similar Gigabyte Brix machine that has a similar cable, but that one has the power+sata in one cable and I think this one might need two cables (or one cable with two ends that plug into the motherboard).  It's got to have 90 degree angle on the power/sata plug and be only about 4-5 inches long.

I've been doing quite a bit of looking for this, but I don't even know what the cable is called.

Comment: posted long ago, but I'm in a similar boat - I saw a number of cables that MIGHT be what you're looking for here:  http://www.microsatacables.com/cables/22-pin-sata -- another possibility is to google for "intel nuc sata cables" and there are a whole bunch of possibilities.  One of those might do the trick for you.

Comment: @ljw thanks! I think I might be able to finagle something with that - I see the right angle adapter they have for sale, that could help